# Weird Unreal FString behaviour when storing values in a tree-like structure

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I'm currently trying to create a tree-like structure for a UE4 assignment game I'm currently working on to make a text based "choose your own adventure" game.

This is what is stored in each node of the tree, with each node being a EventSystem_Event cpp class and an FString relating to the text that will appear on the button relating to that path.

[image]

And this is a test tree that simply leads to four dead end events.
[image]

Now for the weird part.
This is how I'm populating each node in the tree:
[image]

And, as I step through the variables, they seem to get assigned correctly. BUT!

The moment I check the final result of testEvent I get this weird garbled mess, and when I try to access the data is defines it as "invalid".
[image]
As you can see, the data in the very top node is set correctly ("Test event text 1"), but any further nodes seem to have their text all jumbled up with garbage characters. I've tried setting the FStrings with FString(TEXT()) but that still didn't work.

Is there something blazingly obvious that I'm missing C++ wise, or is Unreal broken?

Comment: The m_Option_x_Event data members are pointers to EventSystem_Event objects, which are initialized to the address of short living temporary objects in the stack. Reconsider your data model and ownership of the sub-objects; have a look at std::vector or std::unique for each _x_.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please post code as plain text instead of as images

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it's recommended to use the TEXT() macro for any literals used in UE4/5, i.e. `TEXT("text here")` instead of simply `"text here"`.